# spliting strings and reversing them

Tags: java, string, math, split, reverse

I need to split strings into 3s and then reverse every 1st, 3rd, etc of strings
eg for 1234567890, the code will split the string into 123, 456, 789, 0 and then reverse 123 and 456 into 321 and 654. 456 and 0 will remain unchanged. The result will be 3214569870

My current code is

```
public static void main (String[] args)
String sr ="1234567890"
system.out.println (".")

public static int splitreverse (String a) {

for (int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++);
    {
        if i%3=0;
        newa [i] = a[a.length - i - 1]; 
    }       
    return a;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well.. You're stuck where you should begin..

Comment: You haven't actually made an attempt at this. For things that are trivial for most users here, we would like to see your effort and we can help you if you don't get your desired result. Otherwise the question seems like a "can you do this homework problem for me?" type of question.

Comment: i'm thinking of a for loop of sorts to split the strings and then another for loop to reverse them but i'm not sure how it will work

Comment: You should at least try it.

Comment: i did my code is so stupid that i didn't think its worth posting here. if you will like me to post it then i will dig it up

Comment: @DickSmith edit this one.

Comment: added my code which is probably totally wrong

Comment: Divide your problem into smaller steps: create separate methods which will (1) return reversed version of string, (2) create list (or array) or *substrings* of length 3 (or less).

Comment: remove the colon after the if `if i%3=0;` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html#fixedLength%28int%29

Splitter.fixedLength(int)

Splits strings into substrings of the specified fixed length. The last piece can be smaller than length, but will never be empty.

Comment: This is only half the problem.

Comment: you can split it(length 1) and print revert